# Chrome not using on-demand Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, nvidia-prime

In ubuntu 22.04 I have set `prime-select` `on-demand` I can launch an app to run with de dedicated GPU with a right-click and click “Launch using dedicated graphics card” which works fine for almost all other apps but not for Google Chrome `Version 103.0.5060.114`. But if I go for `performance mode` in prime select e.g. selecting Nvidia only then chrome works fine.

Comment: Everything works with the dGPU Nvidia if performance is selected.

Comment: How do I work it for chrome in on-demand mode?

Answer (score 1):

Same here with chrome 114.0.5735.90 on Ubuntu 22.04.2

I'm using OnShape CAD software and it struggles with the integrated graphics. https://cad.onshape.com/check gives

```
Measured triangles per second 119.0 million
Measured lines per second 47.9 million
```

Setting performance mode increase the performance, but with on demand starting with "launch with discrete graphics card" reverts to software rendering. In contrast I can use "launch with discrete graphics card" with firefox and get good performance, so that's my current work-around. It would be nice to understand why Chrome doesn't support this.

Nvidia driver is listed as -530 in the additional drivers utility, and gives

```
Measured triangles per second 172.7 million
Measured lines per second 120.8 million
```

Answer (score -2):

"On demand" mode, as the name suggests, is supposed to run with the iGPU by default and switch to the dGPU only if there's software demanding it.

Web browsers run perfectly with any iGPU. Games and similarly demanding 3D apps are what triggers the graphics switch.

Not only the "on demand" feature is a new and sort of still experimental thing with Intel+Nvidia hybrid graphics in Linux - it has been a feature in Windows drivers for many years now -, it's not guaranteed to work as intended in many situations and it doesn't allow the per app settings like in Windows.

In conclusion, there's no way to force it to trigger the dGPU Nvidia in Linux the same way you would do in Windows for a specific app but also there's absolutely NO REASON to do that at all for web browsers. That said, if you really want to, the only way is to select the performance profile (Nvidia) and reboot. Until changed back to "on demand" or power saving everything will run with Nvidia.

Comment: there are demanding 3D apps that run in the browser; people are running just about everything in the browser these days if they can. We constantly demand people think outside the box, and yet: nobody: Stack Exchange users: why would you do that

Comment: @Shanteva Your comment is completely unrelated. Web browsers do NOT trigger the high performance mode (Nvidia) in any OS, period. If you need it - again, you don't even if running the alluded "demanding 3D apps" - then select and work with such mode ONLY.